# Create a Record using 4 foreign keys from a html form in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

I am making a Medical System as part of my Uni Assignment. 
I Have 5 Mysql Tables.

```
MySQL Tables
-------------------
    - Patients
    - Doctors 
    - Conditions 
    - Medication
    - Visit
```

I have populated all the tables with relevant info using input forms. The visit table i have put 2 entries using INPUT on phpmyadmin.

The visit table looks like this

[image]

My question is, how do it create a record using the different tables to create a record in the visit using html form (populated with data from tables, i can do this part).

The information in the table as you can see in the image is just the ID's of the column in that table. how do i get it to out then output it in a html list with the say patient name, doctors name, medication name and condition name instead of just the id number.

If this isnt clear please let me know I will try and reword it.

Comment: side note: Something is off with these tables approach.. What if a patient gets multiple meds from a doctor to battle a condition at one sitting (visit)?  Then you need two or more visit records to record that.. Might be more logical to make a visit_medication table where you store the visit_id and medition_id

Comment: as i say, im new to mysql, sql and php. So advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use Join. for more check this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html